# Can all of the classes in my .NET application be internal?

Tags: .net

Note: *application*, as opposed to libraries.

I've got a WPF application. It's broken down into a main application project and associated class libraries.

Are there any circumstances where any of the classes *in the main application* need to be `public`, as opposed to `internal`? For example, do data bindings or WPF value converters need to be public, if the XAML is in the same assembly?

Comment: I usually make all of my classes in apps be `internal` everywhere unless I can't get away with making them `private` or `protected`.

Comment: @Ho1, protected and private classes are only possible with nested classes... Not a common case.

Comment: Update to explain some of my confusion: the default XAML template makes the generated class `public`. This then tends to encroach upon other parts of the code, meaning that more is public than needs to be. Using `x:ClassModifier="internal"` sorts out the XAML...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are planning on referencing your EXE from another application, there is no reason your classes can not exclusively be `internal`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't plan on any of the classes interacting outside of the application executable, you should be fine.

Obviously, this would be different if your app started using different assemblies to segregate the code.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

You should use the [Principle of Least Privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to govern how your classes interact.  If they don't need to be visible outside the immediate assembly, use `internal`.  If they will only ever be used by one other class, make them a `private` nested class.  And so on.